# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (asset-pipeline)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asset-pipeline

I am dealing with an `Announcement` class which I use to load information through an API when an event is called.

```
Announcement = function Announcement (id) {

    var id = id;    
    var vars = {};

    this.load = function load () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/announcements/' + id,
            dateType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                vars = data.announcement;
            }
        });     
    }

    this.getVars = function getVars() {
        return vars;
    }
}
```

This is my event:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    Dynatable.selector.bind('dynatable:afterUpdate', function (rows) {
        $('.dy-button').on('click', function (event) {
            var record = $(this).attr('record');
            var Announcement = new Announcement(record);
            Announcement.load();
        });
    });
});
```

The two pieces of code are in different files however they are concatenated with an asset-pipeline. The Announcement class is loaded first.

When I reach:

```
var Announcement = new Announcement(record);
```

It says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have been trying to fix it for the past day.

Comment: What happens if you change `$(window).ready` to `$(document).ready`? Just curious if those are different events...

Comment: @War10ck It's the same thing.

Comment: Interesting. You should consider changing your variable name within the function. You're effectively overwriting the global scope within the function with the newly created object. Is that your actual intention?

Comment: That's... not really my intention. Such a stupid thing. I am doing the same thing though with another class `User`. Why does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is variable hoisting. Your code is being executed as it was been written like this

```
$('.dy-button').on('click', function (event) {
  var record;
  var Announcement; 

  record = $(this).attr('record');
  Announcement = new Announcement(record);
  Announcement.load();
});
```

Local variable Announcement has overridden the public one.

This may be a [good read](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) to get into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Announcement name from the function.

```
Announcement = function Announcement (id) {
```

to

```
Announcement = function (id) {
```

Or remove `var Announcement =` right before function.

Comment: It does not fix it. Your suggestion just makes the function anonymous. Mine makes a named function instead. [Refer to here.](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions)

Answer (score 0):

You've got `var id = id`, this should be `this.id = id`.

You don't want it to be
`Announcement = function Announcement(id){...`.
 Should just be
`function Announcment(id) {...`

Comment: `this.id` makes the property public, which is what I don't want to.